# esp32camera , oled display and rtc ds3231

Tags: camera, esp32, arduino-esp32, timelapse

Does anyone know te connections of esp32cam , rtc ds3231 and oled display.
These are my conenctions :

1.ESP32CAM to ESP32-CAM MB​

5V on ESP32-CAM  -->  5V pin on ESP32CAM-MB​

GND on ESP32-CAM --> All GND pin on ESP32CAM-MB​

TX pin on ESP32-CAM --> RX pin ESP32CAM-MB​

RX pin on ESP32-CAM --> TX pin on ESP32CAM-MB

2. OLED Display (SSD1306)​

VCC --> 3.3 on ESP32Cam​

Common GND​

SDA --> GPIO pin 2 ​

SCL --> GPIO pin 14

3. DS3231 RTC​

VCC --> 3.3 on ESP32Cam​

Common GND​

SDA --> GPIO pin 2 ​

SCL --> GPIO pin 14

i wnated to create a timelapse camera where it can take picture with datetime and store it in sdcard